# Flink get RuntimeContext

Tags: scala, apache-flink, illegalstateexception

In my Flink code I am using a custom input format, which throws an exception. It seems I need an instance of `RuntimeContext`, but how can I get one?

My format class looks like this:

```scala
MyInputFormat extends org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat[T]{
@transient var lineCounter: IntCounter = _
override def open(split: FileInputSplit): Unit = {
    super.open(split)
    lineCounter = new IntCounter()
    getRuntimeContext.addAccumulator("rowsInFile", lineCounter) // this line throws IllegalStateException
```

My main program looks like this:

```scala
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val format = new MyInputFormat
env.readFile(format, inputFile.getAbsolutePath) // throws exception
```

The exception that gets thrown:

```scala
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The runtime context has not been initialized yet. Try accessing it in one of the other life cycle methods.
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.RichInputFormat.getRuntimeContext(RichInputFormat.java:51)
```

My class needs a `RuntimeContext` because it extends `DelimitedInputFormat` which extends... `RichInputFormat`

```scala
public abstract class DelimitedInputFormat<OT> extends FileInputFormat<OT>
public abstract class FileInputFormat<OT> extends RichInputFormat<OT, FileInputSplit>
public abstract class RichInputFormat<OT, T extends InputSplit> implements InputFormat<OT, T>
    private transient RuntimeContext runtimeContext;
    public void setRuntimeContext(RuntimeContext t)
    public RuntimeContext getRuntimeContext()
```

So any instance of `RichInputFormat` expects us to `setRuntimeContext(RuntimeContext t)` after it's created.

I expect I should be doing the following:

```scala
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val runtimeContext: RuntimeContext = ??? // How do I get this?
val format = new MyInputFormat
format.setRuntimeContext(runtimeContext)
env.readFile(format, inputFile.getAbsolutePath) // no longer throws exception
```

But how do I get an instance of RuntimeContext?
The exception gets thrown because my custom input format does not have a `RuntimeContext`. I would set one, but I don't know where to get it.

Comment: Where do you call this method? In the constructor? You should use one of the lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should init the RuntimeContext in the lifecycle methods like `open`

```scala
MyInputFormat extends org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat[T] {

override def  openInputFormat() = {
    getRuntimeContext.addAccumulator("rowsInFile", lineCounter)
}
```

Comment: Please tell me more. I am new at this. In the open() method I can certainly set the runtime context, but to what? Where do I get one? This is what I am doing, and it throws an exception from getRuntimeContext() because the runtime context is not set.

Comment: Sorry typing on a cell phone. As far as I understood you, you wanted this RuntimeContext to initialise an accumulator. You do NOT need to set the RuntimeContext by your own. This is done by Flink. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but it's not happening. My main code is shown in the post after "I expect...". I create my instance of `MyInputFormat`, and I do not set the `RuntimeContext`. Then I call `env.readFile(format, ...)` which throws, because no one has set the `RuntimeContext`. What am I doing wrong? This is my first Flink app.

Comment: Can you show the entire callstack? Didn't you somewhere call this `getRuntimeContext.addAccumulator("rowsInFile...`?

Comment: Sorry @radumanolescu can't see the new stacktrace? Do you have your code somewhere on github? As far as I know you don't need to set a runtime context manually. All your code which is excessing the RuntimeContext should do this in a lifecycle method.

Comment: I can confirm that the `RuntimeContext` should be set by the framework, not in the user code. For some reason, for my production code (`MyInputFormat`) this is not happening, so there must be something in there that I am not doing right. I got it to work with simpler examples, and I am digging through to find out what the actual issue is.

Comment: @radumanolescu Do you have a this example on github (or somewhere else) to dig into it.

Comment: Cannot post code, because it's proprietary. I'll post fragments when possible

Comment: Is it possible to see some more line of the callstack? Starting with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The runtime context has not been initialized yet. Try accessing it in one of the other life cycle methods.
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.RichInputFormat.getRuntimeContext(RichInputFormat.java:51)
`
I guess the next line will point to your addAccumulator function and this one again to open. BTW Do you call open by yourself? You shouldn't do so.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue in Flink. It looks like setRuntimeContext is called automatically underneath the hood by Flink, and not during the `open` call, and I could not find any obvious documentation explaining this. But you can do something like

```
lazy val acc = getRuntimeContext.addAccumulator(accName, acc)
```

in your class definition, and then call

```
acc.add(v)
```

at some other point in your code where this guaranteed to be initialized, eg in one of the overriden methods of the Flink class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet understand why, but it seems that `MyInputFormat` is being instantiated several times, including before the `RuntimeContext` is available. However, despite all this, the job works and computes what it needs to do. I have worked around this problem by enclosing all calls to `addAccumulator(,)` in a `try`, like so:

```
  private def addAccumulator(accName: String, acc: SimpleAccumulator[_]): Unit = {
    try {
      val rc = getRuntimeContext.getAccumulator(accName) // throws if RuntimeContext not yet set
      if (rc == null) getRuntimeContext.addAccumulator(accName, acc)
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(_) =>
    }
  }
```

I need to do this despite the fact that I am calling `addAccumulator(,)` inside `open()`, which seems like the right lifecycle method. Also: because of parallelism, several sub-jobs were trying to add the same accumulator, which is wrong. This is why I am attempting to get the accumulator first. If no context yet, no problem: I'll get one later. If accumulator already exists, no problem- nothing to do.
This is just a workaround, not a solution - but that's what i have for now.